# Draw order of 3D-Models in XNA

Tags: xna

i'm having trouble with drawing 3D-Models in the right order in XNA.

Here are two images that describe the problem:

Pic1: http://imgur.com/wGPIk&L5AY1l
Pic2: http://imgur.com/wGPIkl&L5AY1

The ball is moving downwards and as soon as it intersects the terrain, the perspective is changing so that it looks like as if the ball is behind the terrain.

If i change the order of drawing, it will look like the ball is on top of the terrain all the time..

Can someone please explain how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the SpriteBatch call that draws your FPS counter in the corner.

SpriteBatch changes the state of the graphics device. Whenever you're done drawing your 2D objects (in this case, your frame rate counter in the upper-left corner), you need to restore the device state.

After calling `SpriteBatch.End()`, add this code:

```
device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

where `device` is a reference to the current `GraphicsDevice` that you're drawing with.

Comment: @dsk I spent a few days hunting down the same issue awhile back. Could you accept my answer? I love points!

Comment: Awesome, this finally explained why my model looked like crap!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a ZBuffer problem. Have you checked that your Zbuffer is enabled and working? Try what David Lively said. if that works, check that you don't draw your 3D models Inside the Begin and [End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.end.aspx) calls of the `SpriteBatch` class.
`Begin` readies the device for drawing 2D objects, if you try now to call 3D drawing this can't work. End makes sure that everything, set for 2D, is unset and reverted to the states before the Begin call.

Comment: When I initially encountered this problem, I thought it was a z-buffer problem as well. (And, technically, it is). +1, but SpriteBatch doesn't restore the entire graphics state. Its one of those power vs convenience compromises.